# RS485 medium range communication

Tags: raspberry-pi, communication, rs485

*Hi, i don’t know if this is the right place to ask but i’m out of ideas so if i need to delete this please tell me.*

*Also, please note that i have little to no experience in electronic so if i make a mistake i’d be glad to know. Thanks.*

Back to the question, i wanted to make 2 raspberry pi communicate over an old pair of wire about 100m (~330 feet) long.

The giant doubt that i have is, can a raspberry provide enough current/voltage to power an RS485 with that range?

Can i estimate a data rate?

Also a bit off-topic question. If thr RS485 protocol is said to be asynchronous, then why most implementations that i see are synchronous? What am i missing?

Comment: Can you give some examples of synchronous implementations? -- maybe they have a good reason for choosing synchronous over asynchronous comms.

Comment: Can you describe your "old pair" of wires? Is it a twisted pair? Is it an old telephone cable?

Comment: @ErikR the wires were used for an old intercom. About the synchronous implementation if i remember correctly it’s the one named like “max rs485”

Comment: max485 is the name of Maxim's transceiver chip. There's no need to use synchronous mode with RS485.

Comment: What is meant with most implementations of RS485 being synchronous? Most interfaces that use RS485 for comms use UART, and UARTs use asynchronous serial comms. Sure, some encoders might use clocked data interface with RS485 compatible electrical interface.

Comment: RS-485 doesn't stipulate a protocol - it's a physical layer specification and makes no attempt to be specific on how you transmit data not at what speed, asynchronously or not.

Comment: Short answer since there are 3 already: 100m with an rs485 is a joke, you can reach probably 10Mb/s; you see it as a serial port (a ttyUSB probably), so you can use the usual programming for it. You *will* need about 100mA for biasing the line, however. Just ensure your supply has enough.

Comment: You have given very clear explanations. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Maxim application note might be worthwhile reading:

*How Far and How Fast Can you Go With RS-485? - Application Note 3884*

https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN3884.pdf

In particular, it has this to say about data rate and transmission distance:

> The maximum recommended data rate in the RS-485 standard from 1998 is 10Mbps, which can be
> achieved at a maximum cable length of 40ft (12m). The absolute maximum distance is 4000ft (1.2km) of
> cable, at which point, data rate is limited to 100kbps.These were the specifications made in the original
> standard, which by the time of this app note’s publication is already 20 years old! Modern applications
> involving RS-485 often have data rates several times 10Mbps, and require higher speeds over longer
> distances. New RS-485 transceivers and cables are pushing the limit of RS-485 far beyond its original
> definitions

> The giant doubt that i have is, can a raspberry provide enough current/voltage to power an RS485 with that range?

You will be using RS485 transcievers, so you won't be driving the lines directly from the RPi's GPIO lines. Search for "RS485 module raspberry pi/arduino" for products.

Comment: I don’t know if i understood correctly, but from what i’ve seem searching you’re suggesting using an arduino as a proxy?

Comment: No - you use an RS485 module with your RPi to drive (and listen to) the wires. See this project: https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/rs485-serial-communication-between-arduino-and-raspberry-pi It's between an RPi and an Arudino, but you can replace the Arduino with another RPi.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but if not from the raspberry GPIO lines, where should i take the power?

Comment: Get one of these for each RPi: https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/RS-485_Shield_for_Raspberry_Pi/

Comment: So this should take enough power directly from the board (?). Also what's that VGA style port for?

Comment: You can use that or the 3 screw terminal connector. I've never used it myself. You might find people with more practical experience with RS485 and the Rpi over at the https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ There are a lot of RS485 questions over there.

Comment: Last time i tried posting there it didn't ended up well so i guess I'll have to experiment a bit

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need three wires, unless the earth is used as a reference.

RS485 needs two data wires, but also a common reference between the chips to keep the RS485 chips within 7V of each other. So at least you must try to use mains earth grounding as the common reference.

But otherwise, yes, Raspberry Pi can easily power a RS485 transceiver, for simplicity you can try an USB RS485 adapter.

RS485 tranceivers come with different speeds so max rate depends on what you have, these usually go up to 10 Mbps.

The built-in UART of Raspberry Pi can most likely exceed that. The USB RS485 adapters can max out earlier, at about 1 to 3 Mbps.

But for 100m length, it can typically run up to 1 Mbps. If the wiring is good twisted pair with about 120 ohms impedance  and properly terminated.

So the speed is not an issue, battling the common mode voltage range without third wire is.

The UART communication is asynchronous.

Edit: I finally found the [TI appnote](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla070d/slla070d.pdf) I was looking for which explains the grounding. I especially like the following quote about grounding, which should make clear that a single differential pair is not enough for reliable communications:

> Commonly RS-422 and RS-485 system configurations are presented without a separate ground wire. Laws of physics, however, still require a solid ground connection to ensure error-free communication between drivers and receivers.

Comment: you could use an isolated RS485 driver at one or both ends and not require a ground connection.

Comment: @Jasen Sure you could, but from where would the floating bus side get the common-mode reference, if it is high impedance? Wouldn't it better to even try to use local earth as reference, and hope it does not exceed +/-7V between sites?

Comment: The signalling is all differential so there no need for a reference on an isolated tranasceiver. The +12/-7V limit on a grounded transceiver is to prevent burning out the receiver circuitry

Comment: @Jasen It's all differential but with common mode range requirement of +12/-7V relative to bus common at any receiver, isolated or not. How do you keep the common mode of the bus side of isolated receiver if you have no common reference potential between bus tranceivers?

Comment: what do you mean "keep the common mode"  why "keep" it, it's not used for anything.  The only reference needed is A vs B  because it's a differential bus.  you can measure the polarity of a battery without grounding it.

Comment: @Jasen that is a common misconception that tranceivers on a bus don't require a common reference but it does read in the RS-485 standard that it is a requirement for proper operation. If the common mode is out of range, like 15V, the receiver can't determine if wire A or B has larger voltage, if one reads 20V and other reads 15V referenced to local ground. Surely your multimeter can measure it without problems.

Comment: it's a requirement for non-isolated transceivers. isolated transceivers don't use ground  that's what isolated means. so 1000V from local ground is of no consequence.

Comment: if you're stuck with a non isolated transceiver and need to turn it into an isolated one you could connect its ground to a resistive divider between A and B, and then isolate the digital inputs and supply.  but you're better off starting with one that was designed isolated from the start.

Comment: @Jasen Isolated RS-485 transceivers can have 1000V between bus side and MCU side supplies/grounds, but the bus data pins still have say -8/+13V absolute maximum rating to bus side ground. Please read https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla272d/slla272d.pdf to find out why even isolated RS-485 transceivers can't properly work with data pins only as the transceivers on a bus need to have a common bus reference. Due to isolation, the bus side has no common bus reference at all if only two wires are used.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous means it has a clock, RS485 is asynchronous because it has no clock, the clock is inferred from changes in the data. I am unaware of any RS485 implementations that use a clock and the specification does not specify a clock. A Uart is needed to decode the data (because it has no clock). RS485 is a differential serial bus, it transmits data over a differential wire pair and needs a transceiver

> Can I estimate a data rate?

You should be able to get 10Mbps if you use [a transceiver (although this one is slower)](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/RS-485_Shield_for_Raspberry_Pi/) that is [impedance matched to the wire](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/7/763.html) (120Ω characteristic impedance)

Comment: You can transmit synchronously in RS-485 by embedding a clock or by having another RS-485 pair carry that clock. RS-485 is a physical layer definition and doesn't cover protocols.

Comment: @Andyaka is right. RS-485 does not define anything else but the physical electrical interface. It is up to the user what protocol/framing/encoding is used with RS-485 - although it is very common to use RS-485 with UART.

Comment: So even though it only uses 2 wires the protocol can be asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, because if you had a data and clock lines you would need at least 3 or 4 usually the more lines a spec has the more likely it will have a clock and be synchronous